# Merging two associations

Tags: associations

I have two associations:

```
assoc1= <|"HD 164019" -> {"1.05", "1.37", "A"}, "* 63 Oph" -> {"-0.77", "0.40", "A"}, "HD 168941" -> {"-3.76", "1.38", "A"}, "* 9 Sgr" -> {"0.49", "0.40", "A"}, "HD 165052" -> {"0.15", "0.63", "A"}, "* zet Oph" -> {"8.91", "0.20", "A"}, "HD 165921" -> {"2.18", "0.67", "A"}, "HD 163800" -> {"-1.01", "0.66", "A"}, "HD 163892" -> {"-0.50", "0.69", "A"}, "HD 313846" -> {"-0.46", "1.79", "A"},.....

assoc2 = <|" HD 164019 " -> {"O9.5IV"}, " * 63 Oph " -> {"O8II"}, " HD 168941 " -> {"O9.5IV"}, " HD 164536 " -> {"O7.5V"}, " NAME Her 36 " -> {"O7:V"}, " * 9 Sgr " -> {"O4V((f))z"}, " HD 164816 " -> {"O9.5V+B0V"}, " HD 165052 " -> {"O7Vz+O7.5Vz"}, " * zet Oph " -> {"O9.2IV"}, " HD 165246 " -> {"O8V"}, " HD 165921 " -> {"O7V+O9V"}, " HD 164492A " -> {"O7.5Vz"}, " HD 163800 " -> {"O7.5III(f)"}, " HD 163892 " -> {"B0.5/B1Ib"}, " HD 313846 " -> {"WN9h"},...
```

I want to merge them into a single association like this:

```
assoc3 = " HD 164019 " -> {"O9.5IV","1.05", "1.37", "A"}, " * 63 Oph " -> {"O8II","-0.77", "0.40", "A"}...
```

I tried

```
assoc3 = Merge[Join{assoc1, assoc2}, Identity]
```

but it didn't work.

Has anybody any suggestion on how implement it?

Comment: You can use `Merge[{assoc1, assoc2}, Apply@Join]` but keep in mind that `"HD 164019"` is not the same thing as `" HD 164019 "`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keys in the two associations must be the same. This is not the case in your example. Restricting things to just the first two elements in your associations (enough to make the point), you have

```
assoc1 = 
   <|"HD 164019" -> {"1.05", "1.37", "A"}, "* 63 Oph" -> {"-0.77", "0.40", "A"}|>;
assoc2 = <|" HD 164019 " -> {"O9.5IV"}, " * 63 Oph " -> {"O8II"}|>;
```

The extra spaces in the keys of `assoc2` are bad and must be removed.

```
assoc2 = <|"HD 164019" -> {"O9.5IV"}, "* 63 Oph" -> {"O8II"}|>;
```

Now your problem can be solved with

```
Merge[{assoc2, assoc1}, Flatten]
```

> ```
> <|"HD 164019" -> {"O9.5IV", "1.05", "1.37", "A"}, 
>   "* 63 Oph" -> {"O8II", "-0.77", "0.40", "A"}|>
> ```

Note that to get the ordering you show in your example, you must give `Merge`,`{assoc2, assoc1}`; the order matters.

Comment: just for completeness: `KeyMap[StringTrim,assoc2]` would remove the extra spaces programmatically...